# How to block user from using GoToMyPC or Teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop

Recently, we found our users install GoToMyPC and Teamviewer on their workstations. 
What is the standard approach to block users' personal use of remote desktop control?

Comment: For what it's worth, GotoMyPc can use a Java launcher, and if Java is installed that may cause some unwanted headaches.

Comment: I personally am a fan of getting users to understand the consequences, rather than plainly blocking it. Blocking limits people, policies and clear consequences should prevent people from doing it if you can trust them. They work with or for you, you should be able to trust them enough. Also you should be able to convince them why they shouldn't, or else you might want to question if it's a good idea to block it.

Comment: @user15580 - Filter it at the network level.  What network tools do you have to filter any website?

Answer (score 5):

There's a few options here:

- Force users through a web proxy set to block remote desktop applications
- Block the IP addresses of popular remote desktop applications. These protocols use https to connect, so you can't filter on port. You either have to make group with all the IPs, or filter on their DNS entries if your firewall supports it
- Prevent users from being able to download and run the applets the sites use. That will prevent them from being able to use the sites

Comment: "Prevent users from being able to download and run the applets" only if you also put tape over the USB ports.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from GdD suggestions:

There are many ways, first of all use GPO rules in windows to prevent your users to install their own software. You can also use Symantec Altiris to log all executions of all exe's. You can then analyze these logs to see if anyone used teamviewer or any other remote desktop tool.

Apart from blocking, you should also educate and train your users. You need to make your users aware that these pieces of software can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I have used (Symantec) Antivirus security applications in the past that manage workstations from a central location. You can deny certain applications from running on the workstations by creating a simple rule that is enabled on all workstations with that client software.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a group policy using "Software Restriction Policies/Additional Rules" to block "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\GoToMyPC*.exe".  If the user is savvy though, they can install GoToMyPC to an alternate directory and circumvent this restriction.
2. Block the GoToPC IP's and/or ports on your firewall.
   https://support.logmeininc.com/gotomypc/help/what-are-the-optimal-firewall-configurations
3. Use a network logon script to run a PowerShell script to uninstall GoToMyPC each time the user logs in:
   "Get-Package -Name "GoToMyPC" | Uninstall-Package"

Comment: It's probably a better idea to block hostnames instead of IPs and that requires maintenance then.